# How do I combine full page background with links (or imagemap)?

Tags: css, html, image

I know there are [many techniques](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) how to stretch the image to the whole page. I like the ones based on "background-size: cover", but if it is justified, I can use another technique. My problem is that **I need to hook links to some parts of this background image with some hover effects** - imagine a picture on castle in the background highlighting its different parts when you hover them with mouse.

Note:

- I prefer imagemap solution, because it allows polygon shaped hotspots.
- Note that I do not want components on top of the image having it's own dimensions.

Comment: If you want to highlight specific shapes of the image, then you should cut off this graphics and make it as background of an element which is should be positioned above the main image.

Comment: Or use HTML5 `canvas`. Using it you can set custom polygons.

Comment: @Roman: I don't think that it works, because it wont seemlesly move around when background is resized due to the background-size: cove. Or am I missing something? I will have a look at canvas.